Setting up Custom Domains For Azure Function Apps Slots using Azure Api Management
I have many azure functions app, i want to configure to use a subdomain of a custom domain, however i then want to configure the slots to be configured to a different sub domain, eg api.mydomain.com and staging-api.mydomain.com.
but i am struggling to figure out how to do this, any suggestions would be appriciated.
I am new to Api Management, i know i can set up policies, but surely the custom domains need to be setup for each sub domain and if i set them up with values are the same for the cname and txt, so is it possible, or would i need a different Api Management instance for each slot?

You can add custom domain to the Function app by following the steps below:-
Visit the Deployment slot of Function app > custom domain > add the custom domain as root or as a sub-domain, I have added the sub-domain for staging slot:-


For production slot:-

You can also add custom domain as a root domain for your Production Function App:-

You can also add Custom domain to multiple API's in Azure APIM by referring this SO answer and this MS document

that would mean i could only use 1 function app with 1 subdomain, if i use api management i can map all my functions to a subdomain.

You can connect all your function API's to API management and map the domain to all the Function API's. And you can have one Function app sharing multiple sub domains in multiple slots

thanks i think i have figured it out, i need different apim's for different subdomain, its that simple, however adding slots to an apim isn't as simple as you would think, as slots don't show up, and when you go to the slot to add it, and you configure it as a Function App they still don't show up.
